# Restore Mlflow Experiments and its metadata from storage account in UI

Tags: mlflow

Get experiments data available on Mlflow UI from Azure storage account and SQL server(MS SQL databaseto PostgreSQL database)

Hello,

I have created a new instance of mlflow with PostgreSQL database, however I have experiments and its metadata(experiment runs, tags, etc) on the old Azure storage account and SQL database. I have copied the artifacts folder from old storage account to new one and trying to import metadata from SQL database to PostgreSQL, still I can't see any data in Mlflow UI.

My requirement is to show all the experiments and its data in UI.Can anyone has done this before, if yes, please share how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

see the mlflow-export-import tool: https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow-export-import

Comment: My old Mlflow UI is not live, its been shutdown already, I only have the data now in storage account and Microsoft SQL Database. Does this mlflow-export-import works for this scenario as well? 

Because to export, I guess the old Mlflow UI should be in running state, as I understood or my understanding is wrong.

Comment: mlflow-export-import works against the public MLflow API and does not access back-end database-specific implementations.

Comment: So does someone knows if there is any way to retrieve the experiments and its metadata from storage account and SQL DB? Please let me know if any pointers.

Also I have changed the database on my new mlflow instance from Microsoft SQL to Postgresql